# Jena: Ontology creation

Tags: java, sql-server, jena, ontology, owl

I try to construct ontology from my SQL server database. tables are transformed to classes and their columns are tranformed to datatype property of classes.
I got the tables and make classes this way :

```
 /**************** create connection***************/
     String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test;";
     String user = "m";
     String pass = "m";
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
     stmt = conn.createStatement();
     String sql;

  /*************create ontology model**********************/

     OntModel my_model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();


/*************************get table name********************************/
      sql="select * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      int count_table=0;
      while(rs.next()){
      table_list.add( rs.getString(3));
      count_table+=1;
        }
      rs.close();
  /*************************Get number of columns of primary key ******************************/
      for (int t = 0; t <=count_table-1 ; t++){
        sql="exec sp_pkeys '" + table_list.get(t) + "', 'dbo'";
          ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
         pry_number=0;
          while(rs1.next()){
         pry_number =rs1.getInt(5);
          }
         rs1.close();
        if (pry_number==1){
            my_class=null;
    /**********************create ontology class**********************/
            my_class = my_model.createClass(ns+table_list.get(t));
    /********************* column name ***************************/
           sql="SELECT COLUMN_NAME,i.TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS,information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i  WHERE i.TABLE_NAME = '" + table_list.get(t) + "' AND i.CONSTRAINT_TYPE != 'FOREIGN KEY'";
           ResultSet rs3 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
           int count_column=0;
           while(rs3.next()){
             column_list.add( rs3.getString(1));
             Datatype_domain=rs3.getString(2);
             count_column+=1;
                }
           rs3.close();
      /******************create ontology DatatypeProperty************/

           for (int j = 0; j <= count_column - 1; j++)
                    {

                        dtp = my_model.createDatatypeProperty(ns+ column_list.get(j));
                        dtp.addDomain(my_model.createClass(ns+Datatype_domain));
           }

    /*************************get foreignkey******************************/
            sql="SELECT object_name(parent_object_id),object_name(referenced_object_id), name FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('" + table_list.get(t) + "')";
             ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
             while(rs2.next()){
                 parent=rs2.getNString(1);
               reference=rs2.getNString(2);
               foreign_key= rs2.getString(3);
                    }
             rs2.close();
    /****************create ontology class ObjecProperty********************/

         op = my_model.createObjectProperty(ns + foreign_key);
         op.addDomain(my_model.createClass(ns+parent));
         op.addRange(my_model.createClass(ns+reference));


         /**********************Check if primarynkey is foreign key***************************/
           sql="SELECT Tab.TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col WHERE Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY ' INTERSECT SELECT Tab.TABLE_NAME from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col WHERE  Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name  AND Constraint_Type = 'FOREIGN KEY ' and Tab.TABLE_NAME = '" + table_list.get(t) + "' ";
           ResultSet rs4 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
           while(rs4.next()){
            sub_class= rs4.getString(1);
                }
           rs4.close();
           sql="SELECT object_name(referenced_object_id) FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('" + sub_class + "')";
           ResultSet rs6 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
           while(rs6.next()){

            super_class= rs6.getString(1);
                }
           rs6.close();
   /****************create ontology Sub_class ********************/
       my_model.createClass(ns+ sub_class).addSuperClass(my_model.createClass(super_class));
    }

           if (pry_number>1){
    /****************create ontology ObjecProperty********************/
            sql="SELECT object_name(parent_object_id),object_name(referenced_object_id), name FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('" + table_list.get(t) + "')";
             ResultSet rs5 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
             while(rs5.next()){
              Obj_domain.add(rs5.getString(2));
                    }
             rs5.close();
        op = my_model.createObjectProperty(ns + table_list.get(t));
        op.addDomain(my_model.createClass(ns+Obj_domain.get(1)));
        op.addRange(my_model.createClass(ns+Obj_domain.get(0)));
        op2 = my_model.createObjectProperty(ns + table_list.get(t));
        op2.addDomain(my_model.createClass(ns+Obj_domain.get(0)));
        op2.addRange(my_model.createClass(ns+Obj_domain.get(1)));

           }
    /***********************END_FOR**************************/
 }
       /*******************create owl file****************************/
           FileOutputStream university_File = new FileOutputStream("d:/uni.owl");
            my_model.write(university_File,"RDF/XML-ABBREV",ns);

      /***************** close connection****************/

                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
```

It makes the classes and datatype properties correctly:

```
    <owl:Class rdf:ID="phdstudent"/>
    <owl:Class rdf:ID="student"/>
    <owl:Class rdf:ID="employee"/>
    <owl:Class rdf:ID="department"/>
    <owl:Class rdf:ID="town"/>
```

But all classes will be the domain of each datatype property for example:

```
    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="pcode">
         <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#employee"/>
         <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#department"/>
         <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#phdstudent"/>
         <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#town"/>
         <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#student"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Although you put some text in between, the indentation suggests that your `for` loops are nested, so that you're doing:

```
for (int t = 0; t <=count_table-1 ; t++){
  my_class = my_model.createClass(ns+table_list.get(t));
  …
  for (int j = 0; j <= count_column - 1; j++) {  
    dtp = my_model.createDatatypeProperty(ns+ column_list.get(j));
    dtp.addDomain(my_model.createClass(ns+table_list.get(t)));
  }
  …
}
```

If the second SQL query is returning all datatype properties, then this code is essentially: "for each class, iterate through the datatype properties and add the class as a domain of the datatype property." Are you sure that the second query is doing what you want?

**As an aside:** why do

```
dtp.addDomain(my_model.createClass(...));
```

when you can just do this:

```
dtp.addDomain(my_class);
```

Isn't that the point of defining `my_class`?

Comment: I've already used my_class.It gave same result.Then I've changed it to my_model.createClass(...).

Comment: @MD The part about using my_class was just a bit of code review. I wasn't suggesting that that was the cause of the problem. What about the other part of my answer? Are you sure that the loops are iterating over the classes you want them to iterate over?

Comment: May be my query was wrong. But i can not find out that.it seems be correct.I've edited the question and put the whole code.Thanks for help.

Comment: @MD At this point it seems like we're just debugging your code.  It looks to me like you're probably iterating through classes in the outer `for` loop and then iterating through datatype properties in the inner `for` loop and adding adding the class as a domain of the property, and so, by the end, you've added every class as the domain of every property.  Why not add some debugging print statements inside your loops?  I expect that you need to adjust your second query to only retrieve those properties that have the current class (from the outer `for` loop) as domains.

Comment: Please Excuse me for question Type. This part of query limits the domain to current class isn't it? "WHERE i.TABLE_NAME = '" + table_list.get(t) + " "

Comment: @MD It may, or it may not.  I don't have much exposure to SQL, and I don't know how your database is structured.  However, given the structure of the rest of your code, it seems the results of that query might be where your problem lies, and that's why I suggest some debugging print statements.

Comment: @MD Why, in `while(rs3.next()){ … Datatype_domain=rs3.getString(2); … }` do you assign to `Datatype_domain` on every iteration?  If it's the same for each iteration, then you're doing redundant work, and if it's not, then you'll use the last value as the domain for all the datatype properties which won't be correct.

Comment: Its same for each iteration. I just do it to fix the problem.